# How To write a server side script using jsp and java and How to run it?

Tags: java, javascript

I am new to this technology, I dont no how to write a server side program and how to run before jsp page start to load. Any one can you please guide me how to do it?

Thanks in Advance,
Ver

Comment: Have you already searched for tutorials via your favorite search engine?

Answer (score 1):

First install a server like Tomcat and start it.

Run the examples that are available out of the box at http://localhost:8080/examples

Click on the JSP or servlet examples in the browser, and click on Execute for any one of those.

Then navigate to the examples directory on the file system under /webapps/examples/

The simple thing is to try changing the JSP code there, and start modifying the code in there to get a better hang of things.